# Laravel Many to Many Relationship - Linking 3 items

Tags: database, database-design, laravel-4

I have a `users` table

```
|------------|
|   USERS    |
|------------|
|id          |
|f_name      |
|l_name      |
|------------|
```

Now these users can be related to each other - Dad, Brother, Sister, etc.

For this i have a `relations` table

```
|------------|
|  RELATIONS |
|------------|
|id          |
|type        |
|------------|
```

Now how do i associate the users? What i have tried is:
I created a `relation_user` table

```
|---------------|
| RELATION_USER |
|---------------|
|id             |
|user_id        |
|user2_id       |
|relation_id    |
|---------------|
```

**Models:**

`Relation.php`

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}
```

`User.php`

```
public function relations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Relation');
}
```

I try to grab the relation like so:

```
$u = User::find('11');
var_dump($u->relations->toArray());
```

Here is what i get:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["relation"]=>
    string(12) "Grand Father"
    ["pivot"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["user_id"]=>
      string(2) "11"
      ["relation_id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that its missing the `user2_id` from the pivot table (relation_user). How can i get the 3rd field as well. Also is this a right database design? Thank you.

I know i can do something like the code below. Just want to know the best practise/better way. Probably something that can leverage `eager loading` and return a `Laravel collection`?

```
$a = DB::table('relation_user')->where('user2_id', '=', '1')->get(array('user_id', 'user2_id', 'relation_id'));
```

Comment: Can you give more details on how you write your model class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i got a good solution to my problem. Here is what i did:

**Models:**

`Relation.php`

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'relation_user', 'user_id', 'relation_id')->withPivot('user2_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

`User.php`

```
public function relations() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Relation', 'relation_user', 'user_id', 'relation_id')->withPivot('user2_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Grab the relation like so:

```
$user = User::find('11');
$user->relations->toArray();
```

Give me the following output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["relation"]=>
    string(12) "Grand Father"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2014-03-17 01:18:54"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2014-03-17 01:18:54"
    ["pivot"]=>
    array(5) {
      ["user_id"]=>
      string(2) "11"
      ["relation_id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["user2_id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(19) "2014-03-17 02:02:43"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(19) "2014-03-17 02:02:43"
    }
  }
}
```

And insert like so:

```
$user->relations()->attach(1, array('user2_id' => 2));
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to correct your model class like so:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User'); //one relation entry correspond to one user
}

public function relations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Relation'); //one user has multiple relations
}

//query the user and the relations
$u = User::find(11)->relations; // this will returns entries in relation table with user_id=11
```

Comment: A relation does not belong to a User. I am using a pivot table to achieve normalization.

Comment: Looks like I've mistaken your schema design, in your case, the relation_user table should be rename relation while the relation table should be rename relation_description. Because the current relation table just stores the description of the relationship, so it's actually just the user table joining the current relation_user to perform the query, while the current relation table only provide a text description of the relationship based on the relation_id.